# Bamboo Deploy via Bastion Host

Tags: ssh, bamboo

How can I configure a Bamboo Deployment Task to use a SSH Bastion (jump) host to connect to the target deployment server to run a script?

I've tried configuring a .ssh/config file on the bamboo server. It works from the command line but it is ignored by Bamboo.

Answer (score 2):

Bamboo doesn't support this - although it doesn't explicitly say so in the docs.  It appears you're [not the only one trying to do this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/13417841/how-to-deploy-with-bamboo-through-a-bastion-host). You have a couple of alternatives:

1. Avoid the `Bamboo SSH` task, create a `Command` task that does what you want, i.e. calls the system install of `ssh`.
2. Use a `Command` task to call the system install of `ssh` and forward a port via the bastion to the target, then use a `Bamboo SSH` task through that tunnel.
3. Externally (i.e. not within Bamboo) maintain a tunnel that you can use for your `Bamboo SSH` task.
4. Use a tool that supports `ssh` a bit better, such as Jenkins.

Hope that gives you some ideas!

Comment: There is feature request to add this functionality: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-13728. You can vote on it

Comment: I won't hold out too much hope, that's 3 years old!

Comment: You're right. And 9 votes makes it not so important for community

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be worked around by defining the host in your .ssh/config and using -J option there. In Bamboo use the alias that is defined in .ssh/config. Behind the scenes it's just SSH commands and will probably pick up the alias

I did not test this.